# What was Akamatsu Ken's role in creating Negima!? Neo?

Tags: mangaka, negima, ken-akamatsu

*Mahou Sensei Negima!* is a manga by Akamatsu Ken which has had an anime and live action adaptation of the same name.

There is also another manga called *Negima!? Neo* by Fujima Takuya which was made into an anime titled *Negima!?*. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negima!?) says that Fujima is the author and Akamatsu merely provided guidance. [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/manga/597/Negima!_Neo), however, credits Akamatsu as a story author (along with Fujima).

Is there any official statement on Akamatsu's role in *Negima!? Neo*?

I mostly want to know if he played a major role in its creation or just basically made sure Fujima didn't completely ruin his series and/or its' reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the info on [MAL's page](http://myanimelist.net/manga/597/Negima!_Neo) would be the accurate one.
You can see in [Amazon's page for the first volume of Negima!? Neo](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Negima-Neo-Magister-Negi-Magi/dp/0345509986/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1358091160&sr=1-2), that both the information on the authors (right under the title) and the cover state that **the story is by Akamatsu Ken** and that **Fujima Takuya is the illustrator**.

[image: Negima!? Neo's first volume cover]

Also, [Amazon.co.jp's page on Negima!?Neo](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%8D%E3%82%AE%E3%81%BE-1~%E6%9C%80%E6%96%B0%E5%B7%BB-%E8%AC%9B%E8%AB%87%E7%A4%BE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9C%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9C%E3%83%B3-%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88/dp/B002DEL212/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1358091801&sr=8-3) too states **Akamatsu Ken as the author** ([赤松 健](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Akamatsu) appears under the title followed by the kanji [著, which means author](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%91%97#Japanese)).